# How are the menu and menuitems intended to be used?

Tags: html, menu

Looking at MDN and w3c it seems like they are the same except the menuitem is intended to be a child of menu and the parent menu must have a type of 'popup'.

But when I look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/menu

It says menu is:

An element, much like a button, that is placed on a menubar. When the user clicks the menu element, the child menupopup of the menu will be displayed.

So with this definition two other elements are now part and parcel to the menu elements use.

So I am confused even further by the relationship of these elements.

**In summary**

I know there is an HTML-5 element called menu and another called menuitem. I simply want to know the intended way to use them in plain English.

Comment: You linked the XUL documentation. So what you're quoting is not really relevant here. You might have wanted to link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu

Comment: This is quite detailed and even shows an image: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/interactive-elements.html#menus

Answer (score 1):

> But when I look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/menu

That is the `menu` element for XUL not for HTML. It is a completely different element from a different language.

The MDN documentation for the HTML menu element is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu

> I know there is an HTML-5 element called menu and another called menuitem.

There isn't. Those elements exist in HTML 5.1 (not 5) drafts and the WHATWG Living HTML spec.

[Browser support is currently very weak](http://caniuse.com/#search=menuitem)

Comment: oops. I did a google search and when that came back I assumed too much.